# Where are the most common places to find Pali/Buddhism Anki decks in 2021?

Tags: pali-canon, sutras, pali-language, pali

[Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/), is by far the most popular "spaced repetition tool" to enable long term retention of learned material in 2021.

It does so using a scheduling algorithm which prompts the user to recall a piece of information at the time of optimal "desirable difficulty."

Example: [YouTube: Guide to Anki Intervals and Learning Steps](https://youtu.be/1XaJjbCSXT0)

In this fashion, it enables large amounts of information to be memorized (e.g. Pali language, Buddhist lists, Suttas, etc) with the optimal return on investment of time and energy.

One advantage to having this information committed to memory, as the monks of 2500 years ago did, is that it can be instantly recalled and used in reasoning. In this fashion, memorization creates the conditions whereby deeper insights into the truth of existence can be extracted more quickly.

I have a strong intuition that this might be part of the reason why arahats were more common at the time of the Buddha than they seem to be today. For this reason, I strongly suspect that spaced repetition practice would be helpful for those intent on mastering the skill of nibbana.

I know that many Buddhists use this tool and that many shared decks exist.
However, I have not been able to find any listing of Anki decks for Buddhism thus far.
Where are the most common places to find Pali/Buddhism Anki decks in 2021?

Comment: I can find [Buddhism AnkiWeb](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/4259368331), [Buddhist Practices for AQA GCSE AnkiWeb](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/175069418) and [Dictionary of Pali Buddhist terms (from Access to Insight) AnkiWeb](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/155639978).

Comment: @ruben2020: This is useful. These are rather small decks. I was hoping that a more comprehensive collection existed somewhere.

Comment: Out of the 84,000 teachings, there are only certain types of teachings that are suitable for you. Why not locate those, like a garland maker would carefully select flowers from a meadow adorned with many flowers, and focus solely on the arrangement of those teachings.

Comment: @Max: Agreed. I am hoping that an effort to extract and organize the key ideas (from different perspectives) while retaining connectivity to the original teachings, will help others to more efficiently navigate the teachings and end their suffering more quickly than would otherwise be possible. My strong intuition is that anki decks will be the infrastructure of the emergent internet-based "hive mind" AnkiPedia which will make this possible. https://bit.ly/2WhFj9r

Comment: Interesting. Whenever I see the word 'decentralized' my mind lights up. However, there are challenging questions I would like to ask about this - complex questions about the flow of information on such a potentially apocalyptic substrate. It reminds me of the blockchain technology called the Internet Computer. I'm aware that I'm drifting beyond the parameters of this site, so be well with your quest.

Comment: @Max: Difficult to predict the short term future with accuracy. In the long term, however, if unmet human needs exist, we will find a way to meet them fully. The need to help people who are suffering find a more skillful way to end that suffering faster exists. The need is large. We will find a way to meet that need.